# Getting CookieStore::CookieOverflow in Jruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I am getting the following error

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  ActionController::Session::CookieStore::CookieOverflow
    D:\apps/Apache/tomcat-6.0.24/temp/1-epap/WEB-INF/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:102:in `call'
    D:\apps/Apache/tomcat-6.0.24/temp/1-epap/WEB-INF/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:11:in `call'
    D:\apps/Apache/tomcat-6.0.24/temp/1-epap/WEB-INF/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
    D:/apps/Apache/tomcat-6.0.24/work/Catalina/localhost/epap/loader/rack/adapter/rails.rb:35:in `serve_rails'
    D:/apps/Apache/tomcat-6.0.24/work/Catalina/localhost/epap/loader/rack/adapter/rails.rb:40:in `call'
    D:/apps/Apache/tomcat-6.0.24/work/Catalina/localhost/epap/loader/jruby/rack/rails.rb:144:in `call'
    /D:/apps/Apache/tomcat-6.0.24/work/Catalina/localhost/epap/loader/rack/handler/servlet.rb:17:in `call'
    :1
```

I am trying to upload an excel sheet via a ruby application. The excel has about 1800 rows.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of information you're trying to store is the problem. As specified in the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage): `Cookies imply a strict size limit of 4kB`.